# How to set svn info response/call result language?

Tags: command-line, bash, svn

I have localized russian Ubuntu 11.10. But all my scripts use stuff like

```
  REMOTE_REV=`svn info $REMOTE_REPO | grep '^Revision:' | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Where in my localization `^Редакция:` would do the job. I wonder if it is possible to tall `svn info` in what language to responde instad of rewriting\localizing all my scripts `grep` stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this chapter of the SVN book can help in your matter: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.l10n.html

In simple words, if you export LC_MESSAGES to en_US, SVN should honor your locale.

```
$ export LC_MESSAGES=en_US
```

Comment: I want to do the other thing - svn providing me with RU response is my problem - I want to make it response to me in English.

Comment: I edited my answer. Give it a try, I can't verify it myself because I'm using git in an English environment.

Comment: ended up with `LC_MESSAGES=C` =)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid changing language for other commands then you can run `svn info` in a separate shell. E.g.:

```
getRevision=$(cat <<'EOF'
  LANG=C
  LC_MESSAGES=C
  svn info . | grep 'Last Changed Rev' | awk '{ print $4; }'
EOF
)
currentRevision=`bash -c "$getRevision"`
```